# Why does this statement involving the function curve() return an error in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

I am just curious to know why this statement returns an error in R

```
>   curve(function(x) x^2, from = -2, to = 2)

##Error in curve(function(x) x^2, from = -2, to = 2) : 
 #'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

I do know that this statement works perfectly.

```
>   curve(x^2, from = -2, to = 2)
```

As far as I know, the first argument of the function curve() in R should be a vectorized function. Therefore, *function(x) x^2* as an argument should be a vectorized function as well because it returns a numeric vector whose length is equal to the length of the input numeric vector.

However, I can't be sure because I do not have a rigorous background in programming. Clearly, I am wrong.

Comment: I think `expr=` as the first argument to `curve` is looking for the *name* of a function, not a function itself. So it needs to be declared externally - `f <- function(x) x^2; curve(f, from=-2, to=2)` . Otherwise you can `plot` the function directly `plot(function(x) x^2, xlim=c(-2,2))`

Comment: Note that the help page ?curve says *The way curve handles expr has caused confusion. *   Use rather `plot`, which will use the method `plot.function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `expr=` as the first argument to `curve` is looking for the name of a function, not a function itself.

> expr: The **name** of a function, or a call or an expression written as
> a function of 'x' which will evaluate to an object of the
> same length as 'x'.

So a function needs to be declared externally for it to work:

```
f <- function(x) x^2
curve(f, from=-2, to=2)
```

Otherwise you can plot the function directly as `plot.function`, which actually calls `curve` inside the function as the last line:

```
plot.function
#function (x, y = 0, to = 1, from = y, xlim = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
#    ...) 
#{
#    <snip>
#    curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab, 
#        ...)
#}
```

Like:

```
plot(function(x) x^2, xlim=c(-2,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or may also do

```
curve((function(x) x^2)(x), from = -2, to = 2)
```

Comment: That is interesting. I don't know that this syntax exists.